# Ray-sphere intersection appears pixelated when using post-processing in Three.js

Tags: three.js, glsl, fragment-shader

I am working on a Three.js project where I need to perform ray-sphere intersection and visualize the result using post-processing effects. However, I am encountering an issue where the intersection visualization appears pixelated. I'm not sure what could be causing this problem.

To perform the ray-sphere intersection, I'm using a custom fragment shader in the post-processing step. Here's a simplified version of my code: [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/miguelmyers8/8xbadsj2/200/)

shader code:

```js
const postVertexShader =
  `
 #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )
varying vec2 vUv;
void main()
{
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
`;
const postFragmentShader =
  `
#include <packing>
#define PI 3.141592
in vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform sampler2D tDepth;
uniform float cameraNear;
uniform float cameraFar;
uniform vec3 cameraForward;
uniform mat4 inverseProjection;
uniform mat4 inverseView;

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  vec3 _ScreenToWorld(vec3 pos) {
    vec4 posP = vec4(pos.xyz * 2.0 - 1.0, 1.0);

    vec4 posVS = inverseProjection * posP;
    vec4 posWS = inverseView * vec4((posVS.xyz / posVS.w), 1.0);

    return posWS.xyz;
  }



  bool _RayIntersectsSphere(
      vec3 rayStart, vec3 rayDir, vec3 sphereCenter, float sphereRadius, out float t0, out float t1) {
    vec3 oc = rayStart - sphereCenter;
    float a = dot(rayDir, rayDir);
    float b = 2.0 * dot(oc, rayDir);
    float c = dot(oc, oc) - sphereRadius * sphereRadius;
    float d =  b * b - 4.0 * a * c;

    // Also skip single point of contact
    if (d <= 0.0) {
      return false;
    }

    float r0 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a);
    float r1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2.0 * a);

    t0 = min(r0, r1);
    t1 = max(r0, r1);

    return (t1 >= 0.0);
  }




float readDepth( sampler2D depthSampler, vec2 coord ) {
    float fragCoordZ = texture2D( depthSampler, coord ).x;
    float viewZ = perspectiveDepthToViewZ( fragCoordZ, cameraNear, cameraFar );
    //return viewZ;
  return viewZToOrthographicDepth( viewZ, cameraNear, cameraFar );

}



  void main() {
    
        float d = readDepth(tDepth, vUv);
    vec3 posWS = _ScreenToWorld(vec3(vUv, d));
    vec3 cameraDirection = normalize(posWS - cameraPosition);
        vec3 center =vec3(0.);
    float radius = 5400.;
    float t0, t1;
    bool intersects = _RayIntersectsSphere(cameraPosition, cameraDirection, center, radius, t0, t1);

    vec3 finalColor = vec3(0.0);
    if (intersects) {
      // If the ray intersected
      float dstFar = max( t1,d);
      float dstNear = min( t0,0.0);
      float dstThroughAtmosphere = (dstFar - dstNear);
      finalColor = vec4(dstThroughAtmosphere / (radius * 2.0)).rgb; // Use the visualization color
    } else {
        finalColor = vec3(1.);
    }



    gl_FragColor.rgb = finalColor*vec3(.5);
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
  }
`;
```

In the fragment shader, I calculate the intersection between a ray and a sphere using the _RayIntersectsSphere function. If an intersection occurs, I set the pixel color to a specific value to visualize the intersection. Otherwise, I set the color to a different value.

The issue I'm facing is that the resulting visualization of the ray-sphere intersection appears pixelated whenever I move the camera. I have already tried adjusting the resolution and antialiasing settings in the post-processing pipeline, but the pixelation persists.

I suspect that the problem might be related to the way I'm handling the depth texture in the post-processing step or the way I'm passing the camera parameters to the shader.

Can anyone provide guidance on why the ray-sphere intersection visualization appears pixelated in my code? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.[image]

[image]